# GetProcessDpiAwareness always returns PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi, dpi

### Background

I'm currently trying to adjust a WPF window on a Windows 10 (1909) machine to be on the right side of a screen, next to a foreign process. Since I need to respect different DPI scales, I retrieve the DPI value for the foreign process by using a mix of [`GetMonitorFromWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) and [`GetDpiForMonitor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor) API calls.

The last one returns the correct DPI value for the process, which I can then use to calculate the scaling factor by dividing it by `96`.

Code in `Window.xaml.cs`:

```cs
IntPtr processHwnd = Process.GetProcessById(processId).MainWindowHandle;
IntPtr monitorForProcess = MonitorFromWindow(processHwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
uint dpiX, dpiY;
GetDpiForMonitor(monitorForProcess, 0, out dpiX, out dpiY);


// deviding 96 by DPI, since 96 is the DPI-unaware default DPI value in Windows...
double dpiScalingX = 96f / dpiX;
double dpiScalingY = 96f / dpiY;

// get the available area of the monitor
Rect workArea = WpfScreenHelper.Screen.FromHandle(processHwnd).WorkingArea;

// We don't adjust the Window width, since the Window boundaries are already scaled in DPI-unaware applications
this.Left = (int)Math.Floor(((workArea.Width + workArea.Left) * dpiScalingX) - this.Width);
this.Top = (int)Math.Floor(((workArea.Height - this.Height) * dpiScalingY * .5) + (workArea.Top * dpiScalingY));
```

### Problem

My problem is now that I'm not sure how stable it is to divide the DPI by 96 to get the resulting DPI scale. Currently, the WPF application is not marked as "dpiAware". To be prepared for future changes, I want to add a hint (assert) for developers that fires when the application goes DPI-aware. Just to make sure they recheck the calculation. This is why I want to have a function, which checks if the application is marked as DPI-aware. It seems there is no way to check this.

I already tried to use [`GetProcessDpiAwareness()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getprocessdpiawareness), but it always returns `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`, even if no "dpiAware" is set in my application manifest:

```cs
internal bool IsDpiAware()
{
    uint currentDpiAwareness;
    GetProcessDpiAwareness(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out currentDpiAwareness);
    return currentDpiAwareness != 0;
} // returns always True, currentDpiAwareness is 1
```

### Questions

- Are my assumptions correct? Can I use the factor 96 in a DPI-unaware application to retrieve the correct scaling factor?
- Why is `GetProcessDpiAwareness()` always returning `PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`?
- What is the correct way to check if `<dpiAware></dpiAware>` has been set in the application manifest?

Comment: It greatly depends on the version of Windows. On Windows 10, you can use GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext. Also there's a `<dpiAwareness/>` setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process (yes it's a mess...)

Comment: Oh wow thanks. I didn't know about the `dpiAwareness` setting, neither about the dpiAwareness functions in `winuser.h`. But even the `GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext` and `GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext` are returning SYSTEM_AWARE for my window. Is this some kind of default value? Can this be overwritten by a system setting?

Comment: Do you have a manifest? When I use an app.manifest, WPF, Windows 10, and play with dpiAwareness, I see different results from GetWindowDpiAwarenessContext (PerMonitorV2=>0x22, PerMonitor =>0x12, system=>0x6011, unaware => 0x6010) or post a reproducing project somewhere

Comment: Yes, I have a manifest. But it does not say anything about DPI awareness, which I assume is the same as defining DPI-unaware, right? So winapi shouldn't return `SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE`, right? I'll try to provide an MCVE later.

Comment: Just copy the XML code from the article in the link I sent in the manifest.

Comment: Okay, I found out, that my application was indeed DPI-aware, even if it was not explicitly set in the manifest file. After setting it to "unaware", all the fonts were blurry on high-dpi screens. With no setting at all, Windows was automatically correcting the application by stretching it. This is why I thought it to be unaware.

Comment: @TimWißmann "*Yes, I have a manifest. But it does not say anything about DPI awareness*" - chances are that your custom manifest is being merged with another manifest. Double check the resources of the final executable, look at what the final manifest actually looks like.

Comment: Have you tested it on other machines? Or create an empty project to test?